# Preventing the Circle in Database designing

Tags: database, database-design

This is my tables Description :

**Users**

- ID
- Name
- Password

**Article**

- ID
- User_ID
- Text

**Comment**

- ID
- Text
- User_ID
- Article_ID

As you can see, i have a circle in this designing , do you have any idea to prevent this?

Comment: Actually, where is the circle? Comment->Article->User, that's what I see...

Comment: this is circle i think : Comment->Article->User->Comment , because i have User FK in Comment table.correct me if i wrong please

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your design. The user_id in article represents the writer in article table and in the comment table the user_id represents the another user or the user / writer himself.

Comment: Can a comment be written by a user that is different from the user that wrote the article to which that comment is attached? I'm guessing yes, but please confirm.

Comment: That would seem kinda obvious. @SamanGholami, if you like any of the answers, please upvote and/or accept ;]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no circle (or, more accurately, a cycle).

Database relations are directional, so what we have here is:

```
 Article --(User_ID)------> Users
   ^                         ^  
   |                         |
  (Article_ID)               |
   |                         |
 Comment------(User_ID)------|
```

You can get to Users in two different ways, but it's not a cycle.

The `User_ID` in Article and Comment probably means two different things, so it's a perfectly good design.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm assuming this as your current model:

[image]

- An `User` may have many `Article`s
- An `User` may have many `Comment`s on Articles
- An `Article` may have many `Comment`s

It is a valid model with no circular references at all.

`User_ID` is used on different contexts; and, even if there were circular references, they aren't bad *per se* - just solutions to somewhat specific situations. Databases such as Oracle and MS SQL support them via *deferrable foreign keys*.